# Can't parse JSON formatted response from server

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON formatted string like

```
var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
```

response is as below. It's a formatted JSON response from a Google api.

```
{
 "location": {
  "lat": 12.9621211,
  "lng": 77.64804099999999
 },
 "accuracy": 740.0
}
```

However I get an error saying

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I checked out a lot of answers in SO. A lot of them say the above json response is already an object. But when i tried

```
console.log(response["location"]);
console.log(response.location);
```

I get the following output

```
undefined
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:

```
console.log(response);
```

gives

```
{
 "location": {
  "lat": 12.9621211,
  "lng": 77.64804099999999
 },
 "accuracy": 740.0
}
```

UPDATE:

When i tried the following

```
console.log('"'+response+'"');
```

I get

```
"{
 "location": {
  "lat": 12.962118199999999,
  "lng": 77.6480399
 },
 "accuracy": 739.0
}

"
```

Seems like there is an extra line after the closing }. Will that make any difference ?

I'm pasting my whole function here. sorry if i was not clear before.

```
    function get_distance_from_cellTower(json){
        $.ajax({type: 'POST', url:"get_location.php",data:getformurlencoded(json),
            success:function(response){
                console.log('"'+response+'"');
                var latitude;
                var longitude;
                var success;
                var json_response;
                try{
                    json_response = JSON.parse(response);
                    if(json_response.hasOwnProperty("error")){
                        success = 0;
                        console.log(json_response.error);
                        append_to_show(json_response.error);
                    }
                    if(json_response.hasOwnProperty("location")){
                        success = 1;
                    }
                }
                catch(e){
                    console.log(e);
                    append_to_show(e);
                }

                if(success){
                    var location = JSON.parse(json_response.location);
                    latitude = parseFloat(location.lat);
                    longitude = parseFloat(location.lng);
                    var distance = calculate_distance_kms(latitude, doclat, longitude, doclong);
                    append_to_show("cell tower: "+distance);
                    console.log("Cell tower: "+distance);
                }
            },

            error:function(err){
                console.log(err);
                append_to_show(err);
            },contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

    }
```

Comment: this is valid JSON, and does not need to be parsed.  Have you tried ```response.location.lat```? Could you also provide the ```GET``` request code, as there may be something wrong here

Comment: Show us the code that defines `response`.

Comment: what about `console.log(response)`?

Comment: did you verfify that you actually get THIS response from Google API?

Comment: Sometimes there are some special chars etc. in response. Check what is the actual content of the response is.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald, that doesn't make any sense. JSON still needs to be parsed. However, OP, if you're using a jQuery AJAX method, jQuery already handles the JSON parsing for you.

Comment: @Andy ah ok, I didn't realise that jquery handles the parsing for you. From my own experience I never had to parse a response like the OP provided so didn't think it was necessary to parse. Thanks for that info

Comment: @Axel Amthor I will post the php i'm using for this in a minute. The response directly comes from [google's geolocation api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/)

Comment: The PHP is not the problem if you're getting this return, show the code that you use to populate `response` (and let us know if you're using jquery).

Comment: @jcuenod Thanks for your response. I posted the whole code. Sorry I wasn't clear before.

Comment: @chaithu we're all learning. Don't stress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse the next level also. When you parse from JSON to an object, it will parse all levels. You get an object containing objects, not an object containing JSON strings that needs to be parsed.

Just get the object from the property:

```
var location = json_response.location;
```

When the JSON is parsed, the values are converted to the proper data type, so you don't need to parse them:

```
latitude = location.lat;
longitude = location.lng;
```

If the JSON had contained string values instead of number values for the `lat` and `lng` properties, you would have needed to parse them:

```
{
 "location": {
  "lat": "12.9621211",
  "lng": "77.64804099999999"
 },
 "accuracy": 740.0
}
```